# Error while calling C# from java using jni4net from 64 bit Os

Tags: java, jni4net

I am trying to call C# function from java using jni4net which work fine in windows 32 bit os however when I try to load same C# dll from a 64 bit OS am gettig this error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\csharp\jni4net.n.w64.v20-0.8.6.0.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
 at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
 at net.sf.jni4net.CLRLoader.init(CLRLoader.java:47)
```

and here is my code

```
public class JNIFromC
{
private static String BRDIGE_INIT_URL="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\csharp\\jni4net.n.w64.v20-0.8.6.0.dll";
private static String JNI_URL="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\csharp\\csharp.j4n.dll";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Csharp cSharp=new getMyFunctionsFromCSharp();

    }
 public static Csharp getMyFunctionsFromCSharp() throws IOException {

        Bridge.setClrVersion("v20");
        Bridge.init(new File(BRDIGE_INIT_URL));
        File shardFile = new File(JNI_URL);

        Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(shardFile);
        return new Csharp();
    }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong

Comment: Error is pretty self-explanatory, it claims you are on a 32-bit OS or you are using a 32bit version of java to run this program. If you want to load a 64-bit version of the dll ensure your OS is 64bit and so is your java.

Comment: @user2494817 When I try to install the 64bit of java on 64bit OS the java plugin is not recognized by the browser since the application is an applet.

Comment: Is the browser 64 bit as well?

Comment: @user2494817 I am using IE and don't know if its 64 bit or not

Comment: Well the browser is probably 32-bit try using a 64-bit browser ( and not to mention it is Internet Explorer so god only knows what is wrong. )

Comment: @user2494817 was wondering if jni4net could be having a function to force to use the 32bit jre?

Comment: Possibly, although it is more likely your browser not supporting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your C# program with 32 bit flag. Or you could use `corflags {my.exe} /32BIT+ /Force`. That would make your process to start as 32bit process.

Comment: so I should compile the application to platform target x86? then which dll do I load on 64bit os  Bridge.init(new File("C:\\myproject\\jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.6.0.dll")); is it w32 or w64? Kindly assist